# req body is empty and I cannot create new listing on my website

Tags: node.js, express, react-fullstack, httpbackend

when I try to send post  request to /listing on my website this error appears-> "listing" is required
and problem appears to be that req.body is empty , if you see my code I have tried to log req.body in different places but it always comes out to be empty
my github project link->https://github.com/luckyCohle/wanderlust

I was tring to add map on createlisting page using maptiler and then this problem started occuring
my github project link->https://github.com/luckyCohle/wanderlust

Comment: Hi, welcome! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),  and [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).  As is, your chances of getting answers are very low.  Thank you!